# Subset of a vector space with basis b

Tags: vector-spaces

If **b** is a basis for some vector space V, will **b** be a basis for all subsets of V as well?

Comment: No. For instance, not for the sub(space?) $\{0\}$. Unless of course $V=\{0\}$ and $\mathrm b=\emptyset$ in the first place.

Comment: Are $\mathbf i, \mathbf j, \mathbf k$ a basis for all subspaces of $\mathbb R^3$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think to the usual 3-dimensional space that is a vector space $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the standard basis $\mathbf i=(1,0,0)^T$  $\mathbf j=(0,1,0)^T$ and  $\mathbf k=(0,0,1)^T$. 
Any plane that contain the origin is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, but there are infinitely many such planes that does not contain any vector of the basis $\{\mathbf i,\mathbf j,\mathbf k\}$.

But note that if we have a basis of a subspace of dimension $m<n$ of a vector space of dimension $n$, than we can always add  $n-m$ vectors to this basis to obtain a basis for the whole space.